# How to add textbox control dynamically in runtime in WPF using c#

Tags: .net, wpf

I am new in WPF.I want to create 3 textbox for each row at runtime when i click generate button. please help me.

[Automatically created textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21blt.png)

```
 **Code behind** 
  private List<TextBox> inputTextBoxes;
    private void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Get the number of input text boxes to generate
        int inputNumber = Int32.Parse(textBoxInput.Text);

        //Initialize list of input text boxes
        inputTextBoxes = new List<TextBox>();

        //Generate labels and text boxes
        for (int i = 1; i <= inputNumber; i++)
        {
            //Create a new label and text box
            Label labelInput = new Label();
            TextBox textBoxNewInput = new TextBox();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give your grid a name in xaml :

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid1">
    <Button Grid.Column="0"
            Margin="10"
            Click="btnGenerate_Click">
        Button Content
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

and in code behind :

```
private void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Get the number of input text boxes to generate
    int inputNumber = Int32.Parse(textBoxInput.Text);

    //Initialize list of input text boxes
    inputTextBoxes = new List<TextBox>();

    //Generate labels and text boxes
    for (int i = 1; i <= inputNumber; i++)
    {
        //Create a new label and text box
        Label labelInput = new Label();
        Grid1.Children.Add(labelInput);
        TextBox textBoxNewInput = new TextBox();
        Grid1.Children.Add(textBoxNewInput);
    }
}
```

If you want, you can set the position also so that the newly created elements doesn't overlap each other.

**EDIT :**

You need to create a grid with required rows and columns and then place each textbox or label inside the required row-column combination.
It contains 6 rows and 3 columns. Please see the example below :

```
<Grid Name="Grid1">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid> 

private void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Get the number of input text boxes to generate
    int inputNumber = Int32.Parse(textBoxInput.Text);

    //Initialize list of input text boxes
    inputTextBoxes = new List<TextBox>();

    //Generate labels and text boxes
    for (int i = 1; i <= inputNumber; i++)
    {
        //Create a new label and text box
        Label labelInput = new Label();

        Grid.SetColumn(labelInput, i);
        Grid.SetRow(labelInput, i);
        Grid1.Children.Add(labelInput);

        TextBox textBoxNewInput = new TextBox();
        Grid.SetColumn(labelInput, i+1);
        Grid.SetRow(labelInput, i);
        Grid1.Children.Add(textBoxNewInput);
    }
}
```

Comment: But how i set the location and other property for each textbox and label.

Comment: Set the margin property like this for label and textbox `Margin="20,10,0,10"`

Comment: I also want to send the data of those textboxes to the database.It will helpful for me if u send the solution.

Comment: That you have to bind the textbox to some property and then update the db when property changes.

Comment: @ZakirHasan: Added more info. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your page's content is a `Canvas` control:

Code behind:

```
protected void ButtonGenerate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    (this.Content as Canvas).Children.Add(tb);
}
```

You may find other textbox property in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No the page content is Grid.Plz give me the code for Grid.

Comment: You may want to check the similar code for Grid on Google.